# In woocommerce cart item we can add custom text but how can i add custom link?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

My goal is in cart item i have to show one link with each product.

**- on cart page
- on checkout
- on order summary in back-end**

and when I click on link it open the link target website or file

right now I can save the custom title or text on each cart item now issue when i try to pass link tag it show nothing but text without link

I used this link to archive one goal to show text but now I need link instead of text.

[link to archive custom text on each item](https://iconicwp.com/blog/add-custom-cart-item-data-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your requirement. it will add website/file url to cart page, checkout page and order summary in back-end.

You need to create one custom field for website/file url in product page. https://prnt.sc/pa7fyg

that url/link will be display at:

- in product detail page above add to cart button. https://prnt.sc/pa7h9s
- Cart page https://prnt.sc/pa7hxb
- Checkout page https://prnt.sc/pa7j43
- order summary frontend /backend https://prnt.sc/pa7jsp   https://prnt.sc/pa7k70

You can change text/label as per your need.

```
  /*
    # add link filed above add to cart button
    */

function output_web_file_url_field() {
    global $product;
     $id = $product->get_id();
     $web_file_url = get_post_meta($id,"file_website_url",true);
    if(!empty($web_file_url)){
    ?>
    <div class="web-file-url-field">
        <a href="<?php echo $web_file_url;?>"  target="_blank"/>Website/file</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="web-file-url" value="<?php echo $web_file_url;?>">
    </div>
    <?php
   }
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'output_web_file_url_field', 10 );

/*
# Add Link to cart item.
*/
function web_file_url_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $web_file_url = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'web-file-url' );

    if ( empty( $web_file_url ) ) {
        return $cart_item_data;
    }

    $cart_item_data['web-file-url'] = $web_file_url;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'web_file_url_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );

/*
# Display link in cart
*/
function display_web_file_url_cart( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( empty( $cart_item['web-file-url'] ) ) {
        return $item_data;
    }

    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Website/file', 'iconic' ),
        'value'   => sprintf( __( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">Link</a>'), $cart_item['web-file-url']),
        'display' => '',
    );

    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_web_file_url_cart', 10, 2 );

/*
# Add Link to order.
*/
function add_web_file_url_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( empty( $values['web-file-url'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Website_file_url', 'iconic' ), sprintf( __( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">Link</a>'), $values['web-file-url']) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_web_file_url_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```

I have tested code and it is working. let me know if this works for you!